# To understand this recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I got the following recursive function to compute the longest path of a binary tree. I'm new to recursive function, can someone help walk through how does this function derive the result = 4 with the given example?
    [image]

```
class Solution:
    def maxDepth(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: int
        """
        if root is None:
            return 0
        else:
            lDepth = self.maxDepth(root.left)
            rDepth = self.maxDepth(root.right)

        if lDepth > rDepth:
            return lDepth+1
        else:
            return rDepth+1
```

Comment: It gets the lengths of its leaves and adds 1.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams thanks, appreciate a walkthrough to help me understand how does the function work with the given example?

Comment: Try it out on the following example first - tree with a single node, a tree with two nodes, etc.

Comment: Follow this link for an explanation of the same code - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-find-the-maximum-depth-or-height-of-a-tree/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive function is a function that calls itself. `maxDepth` is a function that is bound to the current node (root) of the tree and returns its depth.

In your case you are checking if your root has left or/and right leafs and calling their respective `maxDepth` functions, each time going one level deeper (down) into the tree.

Once you reach the lowest level (elements 4, -4 or 18) your root will be None, meaning you reached the deepest part of the tree. The depth of the deepest element is 0, hence we have the following code.

```
 if root is None:
     return 0
```

Now once you return this function, the return value is passed to the caller, which is the previous node. That means (4) will return its value to (3) which in turn will return to (2) and finally (5).

Each time the value is returned we will add + 1 to it before returning it again

```
if lDepth > rDepth:
        return lDepth+1
    else:
        return rDepth+1
```

therefore (4) would return 0, (3): 1, (2): 2, (5): 3

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, you can print the respective lDepth,rDepth,root.left,root.right.

For this question it will evaluate the value topdown. Forgive my poor drawing.lol

[image]

Comment: You draw so fast.

Comment: Kappa, trying to help only

Answer (score 0):

When the recursive function maxDepth is called, a stack of function call is maintained. That'll continue until the basis step(root is None) is reached. Once the basis step is reached, the stack will be computed the order is was stored in reverse. For each subsequent roots basis step will be called and length will be returned. It'll end when there is no more roots to compute.